# Convert multi type of lists into json using gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

How can I use gson to convert my object into json.I have two array lists in my object.I know the convertion if there is a single array list in the object by giving the type at gson.toJson(Object.class,).
Here my problem is I have two array lists which are related to two different objects.

Here is my object:

```
public class Profile

 {

    private String doctor_id;
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String phone;
    private String minimum_amount;
    private String minimum_slot;
    private List<specialties> specialties;
    private List<education> education;

}

    public class specialties {

    private String specialty_id;
    private   String specialization;
    private List<super_specialties> super_specialties;
}

public class super_specialties {

    private String super_specialty_id;
    private  String super_specialization;
  }

public class education {

    private String qualification;
    private  String yearOfCompletion;
}
```

Please guid me how to use gson to convert this object into json.
Thanks,
Chaitanya.K

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/).
Hope it help. Worked for me.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but it is saying you must register the type of error

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String obj = gson.toJson(ProfileClassObject);
System.out.println(obj);
```

This obj variable has the Json which you want.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but it is giving the error that you must register the adapter type..

Comment: are you trying to convert json into your object or the opposite?

Comment: I want to convert the object into json.

Comment: gson.toJson() will give you a string in the form of json not A JSONObject

Comment: Yes I know that..but here I have 3 array lists in a profile class..If it is a one I am able to converting by registering the type.thats what my problem..should I register multiple type adapters?

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to convert. i would be able to answer your question more appropriately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78901/discussion-between-chaitu-and-abhishek).